# macro function for printing

Tags: c, function, printing, macros

if for example i have :

```
#define PRINT(x) fprintf(stderr, x);
```

and in code i append it :

```
 PRINT(("print this"))
```

output is :
 [print this]

if i append it :

```
 PRINT(("print %s", "this"))
```

output is :
 [this]

could someone explain me why it receives just the "this" argument and not the whole string ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PRINT(("print %s", "this"))
```

becomes:

```
fprintf(stderr, ("print %s", "this"));
```

which is equivalent to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "this");
```

[However](http://codepad.org/DpNDeFVg), [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html) (from C99) work:

```
#define PRINT(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
  PRINT("print %s", "this");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @seven: are you sure you've taken the inner set of parentheses off?

Comment: sry, i just saw that you hadn't use double brackets, it works , thank you .

Comment: When not used in function calls the comma operator works by returning its second operand and has extremely low operator presidence (higher than assignment, though).